# SailsJS: How to call event from iOS client App using socket.io-client-swift

Tags: ios, socket.io, sails.js

I have test action in my FaceController file looking for event fun

```
test: function(req,socket){
  console.log("SERVER LOG: Entered Socket Test");
  socket.on('fun', function(data){
  console.log("FUN FUN FUN");
  socket.emit('world', {name:"Anuj",message:"U Got it!!!"});
});
```

This is the code in my routes.js

```
 'get /faces/socket': 'FaceController.test',
```

I am using the Socket-io-client-swift in my Obj-c Project. I am able to connect to the server but not able to emit event. Below is the code i am using to emit my event:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:1337"];

self.socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"log": @YES, @"forcePolling": @YES,@"connectParams":@{@"__sails_io_sdk_version": @"0.11.0"}}];

[self.socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {

    NSLog(@"socket connected");

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [dict setObject:@"/faces/socket" forKey:@"url"];

    NSDictionary *eventDict = @{@"fun": @""};

    [dict setObject:eventDict forKey:@"data"];

    [self.socket emit:@"get" with:@[dict]];    
}];
```

Can somebody provide the correct approach to send the event to the server. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am recently facing same issue to send virtual post and get request to my Sails server. Finally i got solution from [here](http://techqa.info/programming/question/42160089/Send-a-virtual-POST-request-to-a-Sails-server-using-Socket-io-swift-client).

Here is example of my post and get from client iOS Swift.

Connection to server

```
socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:1337")!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .forceWebsockets(true), .connectParams(["__sails_io_sdk_version":"0.12.13"])])
```

Post Request example :

```
socket.emitWithAck("post",["data": ["userid":"1","name": "Hello World2"], "url": "/faces/socket"]).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
    print("socket id with ack------------>", (socket.engine?.sid)!)
}
```

Get Request :

```
socket.emitWithAck("get",["url": "/userchat"]).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
    print("get with ack------------>", (socket.engine?.sid)!)
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks